# IndexError: list index out of range Not getting Solved

Tags: python-2.7

```
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('csvfile.csv','w')
for file in glob.glob('*.htm'):
    print 'Processing', file
    for y in range(0,3):          
        for x in range(0, 6): 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(file).read())
            all_string=soup.find_all("h2")[x].get_text()
            #stack=[]
            #acct.write(", ".join(stack) + '\n')
            f.write(all_string) 
            f.write('\n')
            print(all_string)
    x=0  
f.close()
```

**Output-**

Processing Alkali-Controlled C–H Cleavage or N–C Bond Formation by N2-Derived Iron Nitrides and Imides - Journal of the American Chemical Society (ACS Publications).htm
Abstract
Supporting Information
Vanadium-catalyzed Reduction of Molecular Dinitrogen into Silylamine under Ambient Reaction Conditions

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/ROXX/Desktop/project/csv1.py', wdir='/Users/ROXX/Desktop/project')
>
> File
>   "/Users/ROXX/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/Users/ROXX/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 94, in execfile
>       builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
>
> File "/Users/ROXX/Desktop/project/csv1.py", line 17, in 
>       all_string=soup.find_all("h2")[x].get_text()
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error probably is that there are less than 7 occurrences of h2 in the file you are processing (in the second loop). Repeating on "all_string" instead of a fixed interval would probably solve the issue.

Comment: thanks, looking for collecting data and breaking them in columns in a .csv file . I would like to know the command or method for that.

Comment: Look here http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/